# No covering map from $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ to $S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to see why there is no covering map from $S^1\vee  S^1\vee  S^1$ to $S^1\vee  S^1$. The fundamental group of $S^1\vee  S^1\vee  S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ but the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. Since their fundamental group is not isomorphic, there is no covering map. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: No. Why would nonisomorphic $\pi_1$s imply no covering?

Comment: @runway44 Oh I see. I was thinking about simply connected case and I thought that would imply here too. Then how can I show there is no covering map?

Comment: A graph (in the sense of vertices and edges) is a topological space. It is instructive to prove that any covering map between graphs preserves vertex degrees (including in graphs with loops). Since $\vee^3 S^1$ and $\vee^2 S^1$ have a unique vertex of different degrees, it's impossible for there to be a covering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good places to use algebra and there are bad places. You might be tempted to use algebra here because a covering map induces an injective map on fundamental groups, so this implies that the free group on 3 letters injects into the free group on 2 letters, and surely this is false, right?

Well actually this is true, and we do have a covering that witnesses this injection. It just is the case that the domain cannot be the wedge of three circles.

So instead of using algebra, let's just use topology! A covering map is a local homeomorphism. Where do these spaces look different? A small open set around the wedge point of the three circles is clearly not homeomorphic to any open set in the wedge of two circles. Try proving this rigorously!